# Python decorator that adds keyword parameter compatibility with Python2 and Python3

Tags: python, python-decorators

I'm writing a decorator that adds keyword arguments to the wrapped function. In this example, the decorator add keywords `deco0` and `deco1`

```
def my_decorator(f):
    def inner(arg0, *args, deco0='deco0', deco1='deco1', **kwargs):
        """We assume decoarted functions will take at least one positional arg0"""
        print("Decorated({}, {})".format(deco0, deco1))
        return f(arg0, *args, **kwargs)
    return inner

@my_decorator
def add2(x):
    return x + 2

@my_decorator
def my_mult(x, y):
    return x * y

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print(add2(5))
    print(add2(5, deco0='BLA'))
    print(my_mult(2, 10))
    print(my_mult(2, 10, deco1='BLAM'))
```

Results as expected:

```
Decorated(deco0, deco1)
7
Decorated(BLA, deco1)
7
Decorated(deco0, deco1)
20
Decorated(deco0, BLAM)
20
```

The function signature of `inner`, returned by the decorator, is incompatible with python2:

```
File "./deco.py", line 5
  def inner(arg0, *args, deco0='deco0', deco1='deco1', **kwargs):
                             ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Is there a design pattern in Python2 that facilitates decorators adding keyword parameters? Or better yet, a pattern compatible with Python2 and Python3 simultaneously?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i think you'd have to do something like modify `kwargs` inside the inner function:

```
def inner(arg0, *args, **kwargs):
    deco0 = kwargs.pop('deco0', 'deco0')
    deco1 = kwargs.pop('deco1', 'deco1')
    print("Decorated({}, {})".format(deco0, deco1))
    return f(arg0, *args, **kwargs)
```